# Having issues recording Minecraft with glc-capture

Tags: java, minecraft, capture, desktop-recording

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 and I'm trying to record some gameplay, as you probably can tell from the title. However, I can't get glc-capture to start Minecraft, it returns this error that I can make little sense of:

`:~$ glc-capture java -jar '.minecraft/bin/minecraft.jar'`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

That is what comes up when I launch the Minecraft jar directly. I get this:

`:~$ glc-capture java -jar .minecraft/launcher.jar`

```
no main manifest attribute, in .minecraft/launcher.jar
```

when I attempt to launch Minecraft via the launcher jar.

I know Minecraft can launch and run fine and GTK-RecordMyDesktop records it just fine, I wanted to try glc because I've heard it's lighter on performance.

Does anyone know why I am getting these errors and/or how I can use glc to record Minecraft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be launching Minecraft by running `launcher.jar`. This file is not built to be executed alone and can't be.

You have to use `Minecraft.jar` instead. This is the program that takes care of the login and actually calls the launcher.

---

The technical reason is the following:

Executable Java Archives (`.jar` files) have to contain a line in their `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` that looks like this:

```
Main-Class: com.example.MainClass
```

Without this line the JVM doesn't know where to start execution.
Non-executable archives don't have this line in their Manifest, if they have one at all. Such non-executable archives are commonly used as library modules or modules that are loaded later, like the Minecraft launcher.